# What's # after a field name in HDB

Tags: kdb

I see in one partition. There are many fields in that date. eg. sym, age, height, colour, money.

However, I see this in the partition (sym, age, age# , height ...etc)
and age# has large volume of data.

What does `#` mean here?

Comment: If Cathals answer has proved useful can you mark it as accepted? This will help other Stack Overflow users who find this question in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://code.kx.com/q4m3/14_Introduction_to_Kdb%2B/#1423-splayed-tables-with-nested-columns

> Observe that there are two files associated with the compound column – namely, c and c#. If you examine these files you will discover that the “sharp” file contains the binary data of the original list in flattened form and the non-sharp file is a serialized q list of integers representing the lengths of each sublist of the original list.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation on [splayed tables](https://code.kx.com/q/kb/splayed-tables/)

### Nested columns

Nested columns contain items that are not atoms. A nested column can be splayed if and only if it is a compound list: its items are all vectors, i.e. simple lists of the same type:

```
("quick";"brown";"fox")
3 4#til 12
```

A compound column in a splayed table is represented in the filesystem by two files. One bears the name of the column; the other is the same name suffixed with a #.